# Script for user movement based on OU

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Any script which will read the department attribute of users (under an OU and sub OU's) and move them to different OU named as department ( already created OU structure name same as their department in attribute )..

we have created ou and sub ou which have different name as the department attribute

Please help if you have anything

---

I have tried below script ..its working fine...but not for sub OU...can you make it working for sub OU as well ( now users under sub OU not searching also not moving to sub OU even sub OU is created as department name )....

```
# Moves User Accounts from the given Root OU into sub OUs by looking up the company Attribute of the User Object
# If the OU does not exist, it will be created (the regular expression filter is removing special characters)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$RootOU = "OU=Move,DC=testad,DC=com"
$LogFile=".\ADS_MoveUsersToOU.txt"
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User))"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry "LDAP://$RootOU"
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "OneLevel"
$colProplist = "name", "department", "sAMAccountName", "cn"
Function Write-Log {
     [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
     [Parameter(Position=0)]
     [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
     [string]$Message
     )
     Write-Host $Message
     Write-Output "$(Get-Date) $Message" | Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -Append
} #end function
foreach ($i in $colPropList){
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)
    }
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach ($objResult in $colResults) {
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties;
    $strCompany = $objItem.department
    $strCN = $objItem.cn
    $strName = $objItem.name
    $strCompany = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($strCompany,"[^1-9a-zA-Z_ ]","")
    Write-Log "INFO User found       : $strName"
    Write-Log "INFO Company         : $strCompany"
    Write-Log "INFO Canonical Name   : $strCN"
    Write-Log "INFO Distinguished Name : $strdistinguishedName"
    if (!$strCompany) {
        Write-Log "WARNING No Company Name found for User: $strName"
        }
    else {
        $fullOU = "OU=$strCompany,$RootOU"
        $OUExists = [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://$fullOU")
        if ($OUExists) {
            Write-Log "INFO OU exists already:$fullOU"
            }
        else {
            Write-Log "INFO Creating new OU: $fullOU"
            $objDomain = [ADSI]"LDAP://$RootOU"
            $objOU = $objDomain.Create("OrganizationalUnit", "OU=$strCompany")
            try {
                $objOU.SetInfo()
                }
            catch {
                Write-Log "ERROR  Unable to set AD Info (Creating OU: $strCompany)"
                Write-Log "ERRMSG $($_.Exception.Message)"
                }
            }
            try {
                Move-ADObject -Identity "CN=$strCN,$RootOU" -TargetPath "OU=$strCompany,$RootOU"
                }
            catch {
                Write-Log "ERROR  Unable to move User:CN=$strCN,$RootOU"
                Write-Log "$($_.Exception.Message)"
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd urge a reconsideration of this approach,it's unlikely that you'd really want that many delegations or unfiltered policies.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make 3 changes:

First, change `$searchScope` from `OneLevel` to `Subtree`.

Next, because you're now searching subtree, you'll also want to put a check within the foreach loop to only attempt the move if the current user location does not match $fullOU. Otherwise it will attempt to move each object to its current location, which will error, and is just inefficient.

Lastly, you need to change the argument for `Move-Adobject -Identity`. Your current code assumes each object always exists in the Root OU. When you search subtree it may not. Use `Move-Adobject -Identity $_.distinguishedName`